# Why read() is slower than getc()?

Tags: linux, c

Why is `read` slower than `getc`?

For example, this:

```c
for (;;) {
        chr++;
        amr=read(file1, &wc1, 1);
        amr2=read(file2, &wc2, 1);
        if (wc1 == wc2) {
            if (wc1 == '\n')
                line++;
            if (amr == 0) {
                if (eflg)
                    return (1);
                return (0);
            }
            continue;
        }
```

is slower than that:

```c
for (;;) {
    chr++;
    c1 = getc(file1);
    c2 = getc(file2);
    if (c1 == c2) {
        if (c1 == '\n')
            line++;
        if (c1 == EOF) {
            if (eflg)
                return (1);
            return (0);
        }
        continue;
    }
```

`getc` uses the `read` system call, so why is it slower?

Comment: Because `getc` is buffered operation. It read data from disk once into a buffer, after that it reads symbols from memory.

Comment: Please stop posting programming questions here; if you're question-banned on Stack Overflow, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers

Answer (score 10):

Because getc() buffers the read data before returning it, so a call to `getc()` does not necessarily result in a call to `read()`. `read()` is a system call, which takes much longer time to accomplish than a normal function call because the kernel has more operations to do. When you enter the kernel space, it changes your stack, saves all the context, deals with the interruptions to mask, and at the other end, when it has finished, it restores the context, the interruptions, put your userspace stack back... That's why getc() is preferred because it saves you an important overhead if you already have available buffered data.

Answer (score 3):

It comes down to the fact that reads from disks are block oriented: to read a single byte from a disk, the hardware ends up reading a block (512 or 1024 or some number) of bytes, buffering all that, passing it to the kernel. If you read byte 0 of the file from block 0 of the file, do some work, then read byte 1 from the file, the kernel probably ends up reading in block 0 of the file again.  And again for byte 2, and again for byte 3.  Yes, there's potential caching, both in the kernel and in the disk drive itself, but the kernel handles a lot of processes, so maybe not.

Each `read()` call also has to change the CPU from user state to kernel state. Memory mappings change, at the very least.  Probably a lot of other not so obvious things happen.  That can take time, too.

A `read()` system call changes CPU state, and could entail disk I/O. `getc()` can buffer an entire disk block (or  more) in user space, so maybe 512 calls to `getc()` causes the kernel to read in  a single disk block, with a single state change. If you look in `stdio.h` you will find a macro for a constant `BUFSIZ` which is supposed to be an efficient (disk-block-multiple) size for a `read()` or a `write()` system call to a file on disk.

Comment: This answer is not correct. As per the other answer, it's the difference between making a system call and not making one that's at issue here. If you call `read()` (a system call) multiple times, that *definitely* doesn't force the kernel to throw away and re-read any buffered blocks of data.